# Google Maps Android API v2 creating a new LocationSource

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

A `LocationSource` is defined in [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource).

It is used for googlemap as the location provider. By default, the location source is provided by the gps module on the phone.

But now I want to use a another `Location source`, the location data will be sent to android device periodically.

I have no idea how to implement this interface. Are there any example out there? Can anyone help me with it? The document did not say anything about it.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple implementation of `LocationSource` interface. In my case I'm registering both GPS and Network location providers. As mentioned by @CommonsWare, implementation may very depending on your needs. I would suggest reading [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) about Location service in order to better understand how to utilize your needs and save some battery power

```
public class CurrentLocationProvider implements LocationSource, LocationListener
{
    private OnLocationChangedListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public CurrentLocationProvider(Context context)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
        LocationProvider gpsProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(gpsProvider != null)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(gpsProvider.getName(), 0, 10, this);
        }

        LocationProvider networkProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);;
        if(networkProvider != null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60 * 5, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate()
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if(listener != null)
        {
            listener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And here is how I would use this class:

```
protected void setUpMap() {
    //init routine
    .......

    this.map.setLocationSource(new CurrentLocationProvider(this));
    .......       
}
```

**EDIT** Please not that this solution is obsolete! You need to use [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) in conjunction with [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) for tracking current location

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any example out there?

There is not much to the interface, and its implementation is very dependent upon your app.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location) implements the `LocationSource` interface on the main activity:

```
  @Override
  public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
    this.mapLocationListener=listener;
  }

  @Override
  public void deactivate() {
    this.mapLocationListener=null;
  }
```

All I do is hold onto the `OnLocationChangedListener` that we are handed in `activate()`. Then, when you have a location fix that you wish to feed to the map, call `onLocationChanged()` on that listener, supplying a `Location` object (the same `Location` object you might get back from `LocationManager`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using the `FusedLocationProviderApi`:

[Android: Google Maps location with low battery usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage)